# Call to a member function getById() on null in plugin class

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I'm creating a plugin beforeAddProduct, $this->_productrepository is null finally, i've already runt setup:upgrade and cleaned generated directory

here is the source code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="prevent_add_to" type="Test\AddOutofStock\Plugin\PreventAddToCart"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

---

```
<?php
namespace Test\AddOutofStock\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class PreventAddToCart
{
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    protected $_request;
    protected $_configurableproduct;
    protected $_urlinterface;
    protected $_productrepository;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableproduct,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_configurableproduct = $configurableproduct;
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {

        $paramsData = $this->_request->getParams();
        $productId = $paramsData['product'];
        $product = $this->_productrepository->getById($productId);



        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }
}
```

---

error:

```
report.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getById() on null in /var/www/cloud/app/code/Test/AddOutofStock/Plugin/PreventAddToCart.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Test\AddOutofStock\Plugin\PreventAddToCart->beforeAddProduct(Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#1 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#2 /var/www/cloud/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart/Interceptor.php(86): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor->___callPlugins('addProduct', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php(125): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor->addProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#4 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add->execute()
#5 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->___callParent('execute', Array)
#6 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/cloud/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->___callPlugins('execute', Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->execute()
#9 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#11 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/cloud/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse(Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add\Interceptor))
#16 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/cloud/vendor/fastly/magento2/Model/FrontControllerPlugin.php(131): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Fastly\Cdn\Model\FrontControllerPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/cloud/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#26 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/cloud/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#28 /var/www/cloud/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#29 /var/www/cloud/pub/index.php(56): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#30 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in name of variable $this->_productrepository (pay attention at uppercase 'r').

You must use $this->_productRepository:

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
```

and:

```
protected $_productRepository;
```